# Single Page Application login with Spring and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

I'am creating application which can be used by unknown and logged in users. Only difference is that logged in user can use some additional functions like saving its content in database.

All communication is based on ajax calls, so what I need is to deny access to some controller functions (end points) in backend for unknown users and on the client side I need to know that it is in logged in state to set this extra functions active. Only one page, login form should be in dialog. I'm little bit confused, because standard Spring Security aproach doesn't fit this case. I was reading [this](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii) tutorial but I cant't fully understand it.

[First](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii#the-currently-authenticated-user): What Principal object does? They send credentials to this endpoint on submit with `login()` function but where is handled password check? What if I have my users in database?
[Second](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii#handling-the-login-request-on-the-server) Is it possible to write this configuration in XML style? I guess that it can be done with `<intercept-url/>` in `spring-security.xml` file.

Answer (score -1):

> Principal Object

The Principal Object is used to be able to get basic information about a user that is attempting to login when using *automatic server authentication* *(i.e. LDAP)*. However, you will only be able to get a username from the principal object. With a server JBoss/WildFly, for example, you can link the server to Active Directory to allow Microsoft Windows to authenticate users.

> Simple Solution

First, Spring Security will add additional complexity to your application where it doesn't sound like you are trying to do that. Instead, use a simple **Servlet Filter**. If you are using LDAP on a JBoss/WildFly sever, you can make a POST to `j_security_check` and the server will send the request to the filter if correct credentials are provided. Inside the filter, you may use the `getName()` function of the Principal object to get the username so that you may store it in the user's session. However, if you are not using LDAP, you may make a simple POST to a Java Servlet or Spring Controller (with an @RequestMapping) to attempt to login the user and store the user's information in the session.

At this point, you can filter out what URLs you will allow users to see. For example, the URL that contains /**administrator**/some/other/stuff.jsp could be restricted if the URL contains the word "administrator" in the first directory of the URL.